# Flatten two repeated struct columns and join with one of them being transposed in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to flatten a table with 2 repeated struct columns in BigQuery. Below is an example:

Column `person` has type of a repeated struct with fields `name` and `occupation`, `show` is also a repeated struct with fields `title` and `time`, so example #1 displays a single row from that table.

| person.name | person.occupation | show.title | show.time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Cena | Wrestler | Raw | Monday Night |
| Steve Austin | Wrestler | SmackDown | Friday Night |
| Vince McMahon | Chairman |  |  |

What I need to do is to flatten column `show` in a way that every element from that column becomes a row, but also that row would be enriched by **all** entries from column `person` as individual columns. Example #2 demonstrates what I mean:

| John Cena | Steve Austin | Vince McMahon | title | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wrestler | Wrestler | Chairman | Raw | Monday Night |
| Wrestler | Wrestler | Chairman | SmackDown | Friday Night |

I was able to write a query to flatten `show` column, but I can't quite figure out how to also transpose column `person` and add it to output. This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (structuredShow),
       structuredShow.*
FROM (SELECT * EXCEPT (show),
             (SELECT AS STRUCT *
              FROM UNNEST(show)) AS structuredShow
      FROM `project.dataset.table`);
```

Could someone please take a look and see whether what I need is even possible with StandardSQL? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT p.* (EXCEPT show), s.*
FROM `project.dataset.table` t CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(t.person) p CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(p.show) s
```

Comment: Thanks, that's quite close to what I need, but in that case it joins each entry from `show` with each key/value pair from `person`, while I need to join each entry from `show` with all key/value pairs from `person` as columns

Comment: Well, someone really doesn't like the question or the answers :D I'll upvote this, it's a good response and provides good result for a somewhat similar use case